# python - string to coordinates in a font image

Tags: python

I have this image:
[font image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Jxfr.png)

I want to convert a string like: "Açúcar" to coordinates on image

I tried this:

```
text = "Açúcar"

strcoord = []
for char in text:
    code = ord(char)
    y = code//16
    x = code%16
    strcoord += [[x,y]]

print(strcoord)
```

and the result is:

> [[1, 4], [7, 14], [10, 15], [3, 6], [1, 6], [2, 7]]

but the coordinates of accent are wrong?

there is a fast way to make this?

Answer (score 0):

The order of the characters in your image map does not match the order of unicode character values:  See the ['Basic Latin' and 'Latin 1 Supplement'](http://www.unicodemap.org/) code pages.  The `ord()` function is going to use that ordering.

Your image map is using the old [IBM 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) mapping.  You can try the following changes to convert the characters to the correct integers for use in your image map.

```
text = "Açúcar"

strcoord = []
for char in text:
    code = int(char.encode('ibm437')[0])
    y = code//16
    x = code%16
    strcoord += [[x,y]]

print(strcoord)
```

The encode function returns a byte array, with the integer you want in the 0th position.

This results in `[[1, 4], [7, 8], [3, 10], [3, 6], [1, 6], [2, 7]]` which should be the coordinates you are looking for.